# Adding Strike-through effect in SSRS report textbox

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I am working on a SSRS report.

**Business Requirement:** One of the business req is that if the statusId which we get back comes as 3 then add a strikethrough line over the textbox. This textbox is outside the dataregion.

**Here is what I have gotten** so far but I am getting errors.

I right clicked on the textbox -> went to Properties. -> went to Font. ->
   clicked Expression button from effects and applied this syntax in
   there:

```
=IIf(sum(Fields!RequestStatusId.Value, "GetRequestById") = 3 "Default", "LineThrough")
```

**Below is the error that I am getting:**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       [rsCompilerErrorInExpression] The TextDecoration expression for the textrun ‘Textbox158.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'TruePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.

What am I doing wrong ? Can someone help me with my expression which I applied. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing a comma after the 3, assuming that is exactly the expression being used.

```
=IIf(sum(Fields!RequestStatusId.Value, "GetRequestById") = 3, "Default", "LineThrough")
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! My conditional check also had to be switched around. It works perfect now!